# Free IaaS for development with full access control? (like EC2)

Tags: ssh, cloud, cloud-hosting, paas, iaas

I am looking for a "free" IaaS service as an alternative to EC2 which will let me SSH into a system with full user permissions (create/delete files, install services, libraries and applications from the repository).

Tried OpenShift but ended up leaving due to strict permission policy on the SSH. **Heroku**, **dotCloud**, **CloudFoundry.com**, **Stackato** are PaaS providers. **Rackspace** and **Linode** might have what I need but are not free.

Is my own home server or EC2 are the only two options that I have? For the curious, I want to deploy my entire `.vim` folder and `.vimc` file for development on the cloud from a computer when I am not at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want something for free that is not provided anywhere for free.  I know its a shame, but it is reasonable that companies would charge for such a thing.  Given that you want it for free I am guessing that you don't need much power or anything large scale.  In that case I would look into the cheaper end of Virtual Private servers or a micro instance on EC2. VPS servers start at around $20 a month and a micro server starts at $14.  Of course for the microserver you will have to pay a little extra for bandwidth and probably and EBS volume.  Additionally AWS offers a free tier which pretty much allows you to run a micro instance with EBS for the first year.

Comment: Thanks, I'll enjoy a free EC2 micro instance while it lasts, until something new comes along.

Comment: I would not bet that there will be a free alternative.  Instead I would start working out a suitable budget for this project.  Not everything on the internet is free and and sometimes even if it is then it is worth paying a little to receive premium services.